# Composition of a differential map and a smooth map

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

In DoCarmo’s Riemannian Geometry book, it is written that if $\phi$ is a smooth map from $M$ to $M$, $v\in T_pM$, and f is a real-valued smooth map in a neighborhood of $\phi(p)$, then we have $(d\phi(v)f)\phi(p)=v(f\circ \phi)(p)$.

In this book, a tangent vector $v$ at $p$ is defined as a mapping of the set of real-valued smooth maps at p to $\mathbb R$.

With those definitions and notations, the equality above does not make sense, since for example $(d\phi(v)f)$ is already a real number, not a function, so $(d\phi(v)f)\phi(p)$ is wrong. So what does the author mean?

Appendix: this remark exactly in this form is used in proving $[X,Y](p)=lim_{t\rightarrow 0}1/t\times(Y-d\phi_t Y)(\phi_t(p))$. Hence additionally I could not understand the left side of this equality.

Comment: Can you tell on what page and in which paragraph you found this?

Comment: On page 26, second paragraph

Comment: DoCarmo says "$v \in T_pM$", but it should be "$v$ a vector field".

Comment: @AloizioMacedo as an apparently Brazilian like DoCarmo, your remark is right to the point. Thanks

Comment: @Selflearner Indeed... I was too focused on the "$v\in T_p M$"... Anyway, thanks very much for the question, I learnt something today! + 1

Comment: If it was my own choice I would go with Gallot’s Riemannian Geometry book, but for sake of exams I must self study DoCarmo’s book which is not really suitable for self-study @Ernie060

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. If $v \in T_pM$, the expression $d\phi(v) f$ is a real number.

But the expression "$(d\phi(v)f)(\phi(p))$" has a problem, even if $v$ is a vector field: What is "$d\phi(v)$"? This is not necessarily well-defined as a vector field on $M$ if $\phi$ is just smooth. Luckily it is in the case that $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism. These things also make sense when $\phi$ is a local diffeomorphism, but then you have vector fields defined on some open set $U$ and, accordingly, $\phi(U)$. (In particular, it makes sense in the context of Lemma 5.5.)

As you mention, DoCarmo later uses the expression in the proof of another proposition:

> (...) Accordingly,
>
> $((d\varphi_tY)f)(\varphi_t(p))=(Y(f \circ \varphi_t))(p)$ (...)

(For context, here $\varphi_t$ is a local flow.) Therefore, as far as what he seems to be  interested in is concerned, there is no problem in correcting his equality by saying that $v$ should be a vector field.

For more information, see the wikipedia section on [pushforward of vector fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_(differential)#Pushforward_of_vector_fields), for example.

Comment: Thanks, I had so much difficulty understanding the meaning of that theorem, even asked a question here but I was looking for an answer like yours